# In ubuntu, how to find whether CMOS battery is working or not?

Tags: battery, bios, firmware

I want to programatically determine whether CMOS battery is working or not. In my C++ program on linux I want to connect to internet and update system time if CMOS battery is not present or not working.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used SMBIOS for CMOS data (I use it to query for other data), but per it's manpage:

> The files contained in  usr/sbin  retrieve  and/or  manipulate  several
>          parameters via the SMBIOS calls:  activateCmosToken ascii2enUS_scancode
>          assetTag  retrieve   the   system’s   Asset   Tag   createUnitTestFiles
>          dellBiosUpdate  dellLcdBrightness dellWirelessCtl disable_console_redir
>          dumpCmos produce a dump of the CMOS dumpSmbios produce a  dump  of  the
>          SMBIOS  in  this system getPasswordFormat getSystemId isCmosTokenActive
>          probes propertyTag retrieve the PropertyTag, if set serviceTag retrieve
>          the  Service  Tag,  the same which can be read in the label at the back
>          (necessary to call DELL’s customer service) smitest perform  SMI  tests
>          stateByteCtl tokenCtl upBootCtl verifySmiPassword wakeupCtl

See if this provides what you need:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/smbios-bin.1.html
http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/smbios-utils

On the man page is the link to download the files to use smbios.  If this doesn't apply, let me know and I'll delete my post.

Comment: Can you please mention commands to query? I installed `smbios-utils`. I didn't find man pages for it. I tried `sudo smbios-token-ctl dumpCmos` and few other commands which gave me no information. The only command gave me bit of information is `sudo getSystemId`. Thanq.